# Can we ever "measure" a quantum field at a given point?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, fermions, bosons

In quantum field theory, all particles are "excitations" of their corresponding fields. Is it possible to somehow "measure" the "value" of such quantum fields at any point in the space (like what is possible for an electrical field), or the only thing we can observe is the excitations of the fields (which are particles)?

Comment: Does the electromagnetic field count?

Comment: Notice that technically you can't even measure classical fields (what you measure are the forces and the equation of motion).

Comment: @gented Ok but then I'm going to argue that you can't measure force either. You just measure the position of the needle on your force-o-meter.

Comment: I think you can't measure them since fields in QFT are a superposition of creation and annhilation operators, so they "live" in Fock space. Actually, most of them (except real scalar fields, i.e., self-adjoint) are not self-adjoint so accordingly to QM postulates they can't be related to observables quantities. QED's potential (phtoton field) is related to "measurable" quantity (magnetic and electric potentials) because each componente is a real scalar field. I use quoting mark in <<measurable>> due to the right comment given by @gented (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) You determine them up to a value given by gauge invariance

Comment: @DanielSank yes and no; the key difference between forces and fields (well, the force _is_ a field but never mind, you know what I mean...) is that by definition fields aren't experimentally measurable, because they do not depend on the interactions (namely the electric field doesn't depend on the interaction between charges that you use to measure it), whereas forces aren't. Therefore every experiment, by definition, can give a result which is just proportional to the force (and then you derive the field by making indirect calculations).

Comment: @gented I see what you mean, but I still kinda thing it's all shades of grey.

Comment: @Vicky Do you mean that we can (in principle) measure QED fields like the photon field?

Comment: @AliLavasani What I mean is that you cannot measure photon fields, nor you can do it in classical Physics, due to they satisfy gauge invariance. I'm telling you that as you do in classical Physics and bacause of photon field/potential is self-adjoint, QM allows you to predict a value up to gauge invariance. You cannot measure it, you can measure electric and magnetic fields, not the potentials that is the object you work with in QFT

Comment: @AliLavasani The funny of being self-adjoint is that the value you can predict is related to a measurable/real physical quantity. On the contrary, you can predict a value for fermion field also, but it is not going to be related to any measurable quantity

Comment: @Vicky So if the photon field is not directly measurable, does this have implications on measurements not involving electric or magnetic fields? For example, electron self-energy QED correction is due to emission and absorption of virtual photons. This leads to smearing of the electron ("fuzzy electron ball" effect). So if we cannot measure such processes, does this mean that the position change of the electron due to the self-energy effect is unmeasurable and unpredictable even in principle?

Comment: If the photon is virtual, its life-time is ephemeral, so I think that the deviation effect due to the photon is imperceptible

Comment: @Vicky Thanks for your answers. My last question is, you say electric and magnetic fields are measurable. So, having these EM fields, can we determine or get some information about the values of the photon field (which is related to EM fields)?

Comment: I don't thinks so. What you measure is the classical field that is the mean value $<n|-\partial_t \vec{A}|n+1>$ and $<n|rot\vec{A}|n+1>$, because $<n|A_\mu|n> = 0$. I think, but I'm not totally sure, that you cannot measure QFT fields because as I say in my first comment this fields 'live' in Fock space. What I said about self-adjoint property and its relation to measurable quantities maybe lead you to some  wrong ideas. You cannot measure QFT fields, they dwell in Fock space, you can just measure (for self-adjoint ones) their mean classical values (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) (mean value between states $|n>$ and $|n+1>$), as far as I know. The question is not easy from my point of view, and I have not all the answers

Answer (score 3):

For linear bosonic fields it might be possible -- in some sense --  to evaluate the field at a given event of the spacetime, otherwise there should not be a classical corresponding satisfying the same equations (think of the Maxwell equations). Fermionic fields  are not directly observable since they violate causality (associated currents do not, however).

I henceforth restrict attention to a real scalar bosonic (Klein-Gordon) field $\phi$.

As amatter of fact $\varphi(x) =\langle \Psi| \hat{\phi}(x) \Psi\rangle$  makes sense if $\Psi$ is a *coherent state*. In concrete cases coherent states show properties expected by macroscopic systems. In general however $\hat{\phi}$ has to be understood as a operator valued distribution and the theoretical object which enters the theoretical arguments of QFT is $$\hat{\phi}(f) = "\int_M \hat{\phi}(x) f(x) d^4x"$$
for a smearing (smooth) function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$ depending on the used formalism).

If $\Psi$ is coherent $\langle \Psi| \hat{\phi}(f_n) \Psi\rangle$ converges to a number if $f_n(x)\to \delta(x,x_0)$ in weak sense, and thus the natural intepretation of this limit is  $\langle \Psi| \hat{\phi}(x_0) \Psi\rangle$.
This idea is corroborated from the fact, for instance, that $M \ni x \mapsto \langle \Psi| \hat{\phi}(x) \Psi\rangle$, defined as above, satisfies the classical equation of motion (Klein-Gordon for us).

Personally, after many years I deal with this stuff (and I am supposed to be an expert), I still find unsatisfactory this general viewpoint when I have to compare the theoretical approach with practicical procedures in laboratories. Barring the case of coherent states and $f$ replaced by $\delta$,  how can I choose, *in practice*, the smearing function $f$? What happens if I change $f$ to $g$? I mean, how can I pratically check if the function is $f$ instead of $g$?
Roughly speaking one may say something, for instance, it seems that the supports of the functions play a relevant role, e.g., dealing with causality issues. But the details of a given $f$ seem not important. There is a too large redundancy apparently in the formalism.  And, finally, how to relate $f$ with, for instance the measurement instruments? E.g., Is the support of $f$ the region occupied by the laboratory?

There is an alternative intepretation which uses a smearing procedure with solutions  of the motion equation $\psi$:

$$\hat{\psi}[\psi] := ''\int_{\Sigma} \left( \hat{\phi}(x)\partial_n \psi(x) - \psi(x)\partial_n \hat{\phi}\right)\: d\Sigma(x)''$$
where $\Sigma$ is a spacelike (Cauchy) surface with normal unit vector $n$.

There is a relation between classical solutions $\psi$ and associated one-particle states $|\psi\rangle$ of the field. If  $\Psi_0$ is a Gaussian vacuum state $\hat{\phi}[\psi]\Psi_0 = |\psi\rangle$ and so on by applying many times the smeared field operator to the vacuum state, according to the Fock space structure. This use of the field operator plays a central role in various aspects of the formalism like in the LSZ formulas.

This notion is affected by a smaller number of intepretative issues since, after all,  we  know the meaning of $\psi$. The two intepretations  are realated

$$\hat{\phi}[Ef]= \hat{\phi}(f)\:,$$

where $E: C_c^\infty(M) \to S$ -- $S$ being the space of solutions of the field equations -- is the *causal propagator*.

The map $E$ is not injective, so an answer to my previous issues can be searched along the idea that actually $f$ and $g$ are equivalent if they give rise to the same solution $Ef=Eg$. This point of view is consistent even if $f$ and $g$ may have disjoint supports.  Unfortunately the smearing procedure with solutions is not allowable (for technical reasons)  when the theory is (self-) interacting, i.e., when it is physically interesting!

My impression is that the intepretation of $\hat{\phi}(f)$ where, roughly speaking,  $f$ accounts for the spacetime region where we perform experiments is too naive, though popular. $\hat{\phi}(f)$ essentially is a theoretical object, useful to implement various notions like locality and causality. However,  its relation with experimental practice is not yet  completely understood.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is the popular viewpoint among physicists that fields are more fundamental than particles? That when we detect particles in laboratories, we are merely measuring the integral of the field energy density over the small region of the laboratory? Can you please comment your thoughts on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745021/why-cant-we-observe-a-fraction-of-a-particle)? I am thinking that fields are fundamental and we're merely measuring the integral of the field energy density operator over a local region of spacetime.

Comment: I would really be interested in this answer but I'm not a physicist.  Could you add a paragraph that explains it in plain language?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can measure a quantum field at a point, in the following sense. We know that quantum fields are actually operator-valued distributions, so a quantum field operator comes as $Q(f)$ where $f$ is a test function on spacetime. Formally, this can be read as an integral of an operator valued function $Q(x)$ depending on single spacetime coordinate points $x$ against $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. $Q(x)$ is formally the "quantum field at a point" that one wants to measure. One can show under very general circumstances that $Q(x)$ is not an operator. However, there is a (in a suitable sense, dense) set of state vectors $|v \rangle$ so that the expectation value $\langle v|Q(x)|v \rangle$ has a well-defined, finite value which
arises as limit of $\langle v|Q(f)|v\rangle$ when the test function $f$ tends to the Dirac-delta distribution concentrated at $x$. (One may want to assume that the quantum field is an "observable field" and invariant under gauge transformations etc.)
Now here comes the catch. I mentioned above that $Q(x)$ is not an operator. This means that typically (and again, this can be proved under very general assumptions) the expectation value of the "squared field" $ \langle v| Q(x) Q(x) |v \rangle$ does not exist (is infinite). Thus, one can measure the expectation value of a "quantum field at a point", but that may not be of much use (yet that depends somewhat on the context, or what further conclusions one wants to draw) since the statistical variance, which is defined using $\langle v| Q(x) Q(x) |v\rangle$, is infinite. In other words, on making repeated (statistical) measurements of the quantum field at a point $x$ (if that were practically feasible) to determine $\langle v|Q(x)|v\rangle$, a distribution of values with an infinite spread is obtained - which however has a well-defined, finite mean value.

Answer (score -1):

One must be careful not to confuse formalism for physics. What do we mean when we talk about a field? In quantum field theory (which is a formalism) a field is often represented by an operator. What does that operator represent in the physical world? The field operator is in fact used to define the observables (correlation functions and all that). These observables are then used to observe states (which are the things that we have in the physical world). In other words, the measurement would look like $\langle\psi| \hat{\phi}(x) \hat{\phi}(y) |\psi\rangle$, where $\hat{\phi}(x)$ is the field operator and $|\psi\rangle$ is the state.

So what would it then mean to "measure a field"? Another way to look at it is to consider the path integral formulation of quantum field theory where the field becomes an integration variable for the path integral. In that sense, the field is any solution of the equations of motion. In certain cases, one can have a state associated with a specific solution. In that case the solution becomes a parameter function for the state. When one makes measurements of that state, one can in fact observe (aspects of) its parameter function, which may then in some sense correspond to the idea that one "measures the field."

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think it's very clear what it could mean to measure a field. It's no different from what it means to measure energy or momentum : There is a corresponding operator to each of them. To measure the corresponding quantity means to probabilistically collapse the current state into one of that operator's eigenstates, according to the Born rule.

Comment: The explain the ambiguity that I'm referring to. Say you want to measure the length of a brick. Do you measure a brick or do you measure a length. I'm using the term measure according to first usage.

Answer (score -1):

The comment by flippiefanus is curious. First, that contributor criticizes that the answer given is - if I understand correctly - too formalistic, to then go on and refer to the path integral formulation using hypothetical paths which are even more formalistic. Especially if one takes into account that the paths (or here: field configurations) which contribute significantly to the (the measure of the) path integral are extremely "rough" and are not smooth or continuous. In my view, that is far more formalistic than the idea that one could measure a field at a point. Yes, that is clearly an idealization. But pointlike idealizations appear elsewhere in physics, like point particles in classical meachnics. This idealization means the dimensions of an object or, in this case, the process of measurement, are very small compared to other reference items used. As the formalism of quantum field theory then shows (and therein lies its strength), if that can be assumed for a quantity like "field strength" (by its effect on test objects) in the sense of expectation values, then it cannot be assumed for the uncertainties. Remember that quantum field theory is a statistical theory so a single experiment of "field strength measurement in a small extension of space and time" by action on a test object must be repeated multiple times to have a reliable statistics to determine mean values and variances and such. The divergence of the variance for measurements for the true "pointlike" measurement localization limit is then the expression of the quantum mechanical uncertainly relations. This is how the idealization is to be read. Seen in this way, the formal elements of quantum field theory have a clear relation to operational measurement procedures.

Answer (score -1):

Quantum Fields can't be physical, you can see this from the Equivalence Theorem which states that if I have a quantum field $\Phi(x)$, I can perform a field redefinition in my action $\Phi(x)\rightarrow \Phi'(x) = f(\Phi(x))$, so that as long as $f(\Phi(x))$ satisfies some simple properties, all S-matrix elements (basically everything we can measure) are invariant. The value of the field can't possibly be an observable.

Comment: The comment of CStarAlgebra is unqualified. If "theorems" are cited, please so in their correct form and not some half-baked incomplete sort of "I remember it that way" thing. That is not science. One must observe that the statement referred to by the contributor is only valid if the states are transformed under the adjoint action that is transforming the fields. Then the expectation values do not change.

Comment: That's why you can dress your fields to construct gauge-invariant ones which are deemed to be the correct observables.

Comment: @Guliano I don't think that this has anything to do with Gauge Invariance, it is invariance of the S-Matrix under redefinitions of the fields under ANY function f.

Comment: You stated that it has to satisfy some properties. So, it can't be all functions. Most field redefinitions probably also don't make sense. Like rescalings mess with the kinetic and mass terms in the Lagrangian.

Answer (score -3):

In QFT, it's not possible to measure the value of quantum fields at any point in space. This is because quantum fields are not in spacetime (per the Copenhagen Interpretation, Transactional Interpretation, and others which include the concept of wave function collapse). They are calculated entities which we infer from the behavior of particles (which are in spacetime). When a measurement is made, a particle appears. For example, when a photon hits a photographic plate, it is a real thing and we can measure it's position. But the underlying electromagnetic quantum field can only be calculated.

The wave function calculates the quantum field at any point. But the calculation does not tell us the strength of the field. It tells us the probability of detecting (measuring) a particle.

For example, let's say that we're talking about the electromagnetic field and the calculation is for predicting the likelihood of detecting a photon in a particular position. Here's an image of the relationship of the quantum field to the particle:
[image: Red grid represents quantum field; Green film represents particles in spacetime.]

The red grid graphs the wave function's calculation of the probabilities that a particle will be detected. The green film shows where a photon has actually been measured in spacetime. In this sequence, its path has been measured in 4 positions.

This image is a still from an excellent 5-minute film by Fermilab on [QFT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBeALt3rxEA&feature=youtu.be) [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBeALt3rxEA&feature=youtu.be.). It addresses your question. Also, see this article on [measurement in quantum mechanics](http://www.quantumphysicslady.org/glossary/measurement/) in an encyclopedia for laypeople which addresses this issue in straightforward terms.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer appears to try address a different question than the one that is being asked.

Comment: I have added a few sentences at the beginning to more directly answer the question.